# Can you skip a specific looping instance in a php loop?

Tags: php, loops

Say, for example, I have these parameters set for a for loop:

```
$b = 5;  
for ($a = 0; $a < $b; $a++) {  
    echo "Looped.";
}
```

Would there be a way to specifically target one of the looping instances (for this let's just say the 3rd loop) and skip it?

Comment: that should be a semicolon not a comma

Comment: @nogad haha wow, I can't believe I just did that.

Comment: you and the answers (guess they dont test)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the same as well.

```
$b = 5;  
for ($a = 0; $a < $b; $a++) { 
    if ($a != 3) {
        echo "Looped.";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, that also makes a lot of sense. Thanks! It didn't even cross my mind to do that.

Comment: Definitely the most simple solution.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [continue](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php). For example:

```
$b = 5;  
for ($a = 0; $a < $b; $a++) { 
    if ($a === 3) {
        continue;
    } 
    echo "Looped.";
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for a solution because I knew it was possible in other programming languages but I wasn't having any luck.

Answer (score 0):

or you could simply use a while loop

```
$a = 0; $b = 5;  
while($a < $b && $a !=3 ){ 
    echo "Looped.";
    $a++;
}
```

Comment: Never knew there would be so many simple solutions to this. Thanks again!